# How to run Grails in Jetty?

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, jetty

How can I run Grails in Jetty? I've changed this in `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
//build ":tomcat:7.0.55"
build ':jetty:2.0.3'
```

When I do `grails run-app`... it's still running in Tomcat. I can see it running in Tomcat because I'm using XAMPP. And when the app is started the tomcat in XAMPP is running. I'm expecting that the Tomcat will not run and the plugin Jetty is run instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you considered the version matrix (aka maybe you need 3.0.0? https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-jetty).  have you tried removing your build dir and did a `grails package`?

Comment: where is that build dir? i'm doing mvn clean. Will that delete build dir?

Comment: When I'm doing mvn clean, target and plugins dir is cleaned. I'm testing grails package now.

Comment: i have never used maven with grails before, but i bet, that the "run-app" pendant there is hard wired in the config there.  you might even have to regenerate the maven config file from the grails project.  just in case please update the informations regarding all of this in the question.  those are vital infos and should not be withheld.

Comment: I did grails clean, grails package and grails run-app. It's still running in tomcat. I would like to switch to jetty because I'm always encoutering permgen even if permsize is set to 1024mb.

Comment: and jetty would fix this?  well could you please also state, what grails version are you using and version of the plugin you tried it with?

Comment: in a vanilla 2.4.4 project with jetty 3.0.0 plugin, both run-app and run-war start jetty.

Comment: We are using 2.4.3 for grails. I'm now using jetty 3.0.0... By the way, I'm using intellij as my IDE. How did you know that it's started in jetty?

Comment: i opened localhost:8080 and there was an 404 from jetty.

Comment: Okay. I created a new grails app with build ":jetty:3.0.0". But it's still running in tomcat. I think grails run-app is not seeing the changes I made in BuildConfig.groovy.

Comment: I'm seeing error 404 from Jetty now in the new basic grails app. I'll try it in our project.

Comment: I'm seeing error 404 in jetty if the app is run in command line. But if I'm using grails plugin of intellij to run the app. There's nothing displayed in localhost:8080.

Comment: By the way, thank you for the help cfrick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you've removed the tomcat dependency?

From the [jetty plugin docs](http://grails.org/plugin/jetty):

> **Installation**
>
> Remove the dependency in BuildConfig.groovy for the
>   Tomcat plugin and add this in its place:
>
> ```
> build ':jetty:2.0.3'
> ```

If the problem persists, do

```
rm -rf target; grails clean; grails run-app
```

Hope that helps!